# Function to check if object exists, or file exists, and if not create object

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that:

1. will determine whether an object My_data_table exists in the global environment , and if it does will print a statement saying so, skipping all subsequent steps
2. if it does not exist: will search to see whether a file at a specific path Myfile exists at a specific path location.

   1. if the file at Myfile exists, it will load that file as a dataframe of that name, and print a statement to say it has done so.
   2. if the file at Myfile doesn't exist it will create the empty dataframe as the object My_data_table, and print a statement to say it has done so.

I wrote a function, and it seems like it will read the conditions correctly, but doesn't load the file or create the dataframe object I want. Instead, it creates a value which is equal to the print statement of the relevant condition.

Does anyone know where it am going wrong?

This is what I have so far:

```
load_data_file_ephys <- function(f) {if (exists("My_data_table") == TRUE){
  print("The object has already been defined in R, data table not created.")
}else {if(file.exists(f)){
  My_data_table <- read_csv(here(f), col_names = TRUE, show_col_types =FALSE)
  print("The current file has been loaded as the data table.")
}  else {
  My_data_table <- data.frame(ID = numeric(0),   
                                    Tot_Events = numeric(0),
                                    Freq_Events = numeric(0),
                                    Mean_Amp = numeric(0),
                                    Mean_Interval = numeric(0),
                                    Data_type = numeric(0))
  print("The empty data table has been created.")
}}}
```

to run

```
animal_number = "03"
library(here)
Myfile <- paste0("results/results_",animal_number,".csv")
My_data_table <- load_data_file_ephys(Myfile)
```

Comment: I would strongly caution against this approach. Variables should almost always be considered as *static*, i.e. code should not need to check whether a variable exists or not: this should be *known* statically. Failure to adhere to this principle makes code *much* more complex and brittle. There are very few legitimate applications of such logic. In most cases, the underlying problem can be solved much easier and more straightforward. Hence: what underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Basically, I am creating this empty structure so that I can analyse a raw dataset with a different function, return a vector result, and then append that vector to the bottom of the results table My_data_table. When I have done this, I will re-run the entire code with a new raw dataset, appending a new row to My_data_table. using this function `append_datatable <- function(x,y){  
  y[nrow(y) + 1, ] <- x
  return(y)`} . (ctd)

Comment: I want this code to ensure that I don' t overwrite My_data_table each time I run the code with a new dataset, and so that if I stop analysing part way through the  group of raw datasets to be processed into My_data_table, I can load up the saved file as an object and continue on from the point I stopped. Sorry if this isn' t clear, I can share code if it is easier.